# Security question incoming calls

Tags: security

I've got an Nokia 6 with Pie! How do I stop others from answering my calls, or more correct, how do I stop incoming calls from opening my phone?? Everytime there's an incoming call, all security settings are set aside, and anyone can answer or have access to my phone.

Comment: An incoming phone clall should only bring the phone app to front but your phone remains locked. If not this is a security issue and you should report it to Nokia and/or Google.

Comment: Don't think I will go through the hassle to report this, since there is no obvious way to report such matters (not to me at least). From their point of view I believe ignorance is bliss and I doubt they will address the issue!?

Comment: As I suspected! I got a mail in poor english (I know mine's not perfect but..)

We understand that you have been looking for the way to turn off the function that opened your phone automatically and another person will be able to answer your phone call. 

We do understand how frustrating that could be. We have checked on the application, even set the password, pin code on your device you can pick up a phone call without unlock the device. Thank you for your feedback, we are appreciate your opinion and hope that an update in future the function will be better. Please stay tuned!"

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but having to install an app to maintain basic security feels kinda off? All you have to do, as it seems, is to steal a phone you know the number to, give it a call and it's wide open. All security will be set aside! I know tons of people that have their name on the start screen, in case they loose the phone. And honestly, how many times haven't you called your own phone when you have lost it? All the thief have to do is to wait for a call... How many phone models have this issue? This is a HUGE security issue! A MAJOR fupp uck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Incoming Call Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.approids.calllock). When you start the app:

> This application will protect your phone's Incoming call to be picked by some one else. This application will not allow any one to see the caller's number, name or any other details as the password input screen will be up on the screen.

1. Give the necessary permission.
2. Set a pin or pattern to unlock the phone when people call.
3. Enable the lock.

When you receive a call, before answering, you will need to enter a pin or pattern.

***Note:*** In the settings, you can fine tune how the app should work. You can block all incoming calls or some, allow to view the number that is calling or not, etc.

**Important:** @Izzy has pointed in the comments that the app has severe privacy issues due to several trackers incorporated to the apps that may transmit your data to 3rd parties. Plus some permissions look suspicious. See his comments below.

**Disclalimer:** I am just a current/former user of the app(s).

Comment: Keep in mind that this app comes with several trackers: AdMob, Firebase and – worst – Facebook. The latter is known to siphon data from every app it's integrated into. So you might involuntarily transmit to Facebook who calls you and when, including contact details (the app has the permission to access your addressbook). Further suspicious looking is that an app for *incoming* calls has the permission to initiate calls itself. I'm not accusing, just mentioning possible security/privacy issues, as the app description does not mention them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Secure Incoming Call](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luutinhit.secureincomingcall). It's an app that can lock your incoming calls by setting a password or a pattern. You can customize which calls you want to answer without lock. You can select all contacts, specific contacts or all unknown numbers. Just try the app!